Which continuity class $C^k$ fulfills the following function?
Which continuity class $C^k$ fulfills the following function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0,\quad |x|\geq 1; \\ x\ \ln(x^2)\ e^{\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}},\quad |x|<1;\end{cases}$$
I am confused about what happens at $x=0$, since from the logarithm, without any sharp point neither blown-up, the slope goes to infinity, but also from the linear part it should be just zero since "zero times whatever should equal zero".
From the other points it should be smooth since is multiplied by a smooth bump function.
Hope you could explain it. Here is the plot where is non-zero: it "looks smooth", but I don't think is $C^\infty$, maybe don't even class $C^1$ due the slope at $x=0$, so I want to know which rule applies here.


Added later
I tried it later in Wolfram-Alpha and its said that $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$, so now I have no clue about what is happening: its really undefined at zero? or wolfram-alpha is mistaken?

It is of course undefined at $x=0$ because we do not have $\ln0$ in real analysis. However, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}x\ln(x^2){\rm e}^{\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}}=0$, so $x=0$ is a removeable discontinuity and we can define $f(0)=0$. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\ln(x^2){\rm e}^{\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}}$ does not exist, which is to say $f'(0)$ does not exist, then $f(x)\in C^0$.

@JCQ Thanks for the comment. Could you extended in an answer? so I could close the question?

It is of course undefined at $x=0$ because we do not have $\ln0$ in real analysis. However, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}x\ln(x^2){\rm e}^{\frac{x^2}{x^2−1}}=0$, so $x=0$ is a removeable discontinuity and we can define $f(0)=0$.
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)−f(0)}{x−0}=\lim_{x\to0}\ln(x^2){\rm e}^{\frac{x^2}{x^2−1}}$ does not exist, which is to say $f′(0)$ does not exist, then $f(x)\in C^0$.
